# Count words using Predicate

Tags: c#, predicate

I need to get the count of items specified in a string[] which satisfies my condition. So, I tried Predicate and defined my condition using the same. But my code is not working. Can anyone please help me?

```
string[] books = new string[] { "Java", "SQL", "OOPS Concepts", "DotNet Basics"};

Predicate<string> longBooks = delegate(string book) { return book.Length > 5; };
int numberOfBooksWithLongNames = books.Count(longBooks);
```

When I run this, it shows a compile time error. Please see below:

> 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: please add details about why it's not working

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Rather than using a anon delegate like that you can use a lambda `books.Count(book => book.Length > 5)` just reads better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LINQ [`Count()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) method does not take a `Predicate` as a parameter.  In your case the method takes a delegate of type `Func<string, bool>`.  So there are a couple ways you can fix your code, the simplest would probably be to do what others have suggested and use a lambda.  Or, using your original code just change `Predicate<string>` to `Func<string, bool>`:

```
string[] books = new string[] { "Java", "SQL", "OOPS Concepts", "DotNet Basics"};

Func<string, bool> longBooks = delegate(string book) { return book.Length > 5; };
int numberOfBooksWithLongNames = books.Count(longBooks);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var result = books.Count(x => x.Length > 5);
```

When doing this without lambdas anonymous methods define a method (your predicate):

```
public bool HasLongTitle(string book)
{
    return book.Length > 5;
}
```

The use it:

```
var result = books.Count(HasLongTitle);
```

Comment: Can you please let me know how I can do this using Predicate.

Comment: This in fact _is_ a predicate, but I edited my post to show how this works without lambdas and anonymous methods.

Comment: Well in fact this _is_ a `Func<string, bool>`, but that has the same method signature as a `Predicate<string>`...

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems

```
string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and the best extension method
 overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Count<TSource>
(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,bool>)' 
has some invalid arguments
```

and

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Predicate<string>' to 
'System.Func<string,bool>'
```

These solutions work

```
int numberOfBooksWithLongNames = books.AsEnumberable().Count(s => longBooks(s));
int numberOfBooksWithLongNames = new List<string>(books).Count(s => longBooks(s));
int numberOfBooksWithLongNames = books.Count(s => longBooks(s));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Also, the first one didn't work but the other 2 works fine. It gives this error, 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumberable' and no extension method 'AsEnumberable' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: have you referenced `System.Core` assembly and used the proper namespances? try `new List<string>{"c", "b", "a"}.OrderBy(s => s);` If the code won't compile, then you must check usings and referenced assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
books.Count(a = > a.Length > 5);
```